# NestJS Nest can't resolve dependencies Error

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

Im using NestJS Graphql TypeOrm im trying to run programm but got these error. I did not use any String Module

If String is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within SellModule?
I can't find String is exported

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SellService (SellRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument String at index [1] is available in the SellModule context.

Potential solutions:

- If String is a provider, is it part of the current SellModule?
- If String is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within SellModule?

  @Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing String */ ]
  })

sell.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { SellService } from './sell.service'
import { SellResolver } from './sell.resolver'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { Sell } from './entities/sell.entity'

@Module({
  providers: [SellResolver, SellService],
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Sell])]
})
export class SellModule {}
```

sell.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import {
  createErrorMessage,
  deleteErrorMessage,
  editErrorMessage,
  existErrorMessage,
  notFoundMessage,
  readErrorMessage,
  userNotMatchDeleteError,
  userNotMatchEditError
} from 'src/common/common.constants'
import { User } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity'
import { Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { AllSellOutput } from './dto/all-sell.dto'
import { CreateSellInput, CreateSellOutput } from './dto/create-sell.dto'
import { DeleteSellInput, DeleteSellOutput } from './dto/delete-sell.dto'
import { EditSellInput, EditSellOutput } from './dto/edit-sell.dto'
import { Sell } from './entities/sell.entity'

@Injectable()
export class SellService {
  constructor (
    @InjectRepository(Sell) private readonly sells: Repository<Sell>,
    private readonly message: string
  ) {
    this.message = 'Зарын'
  }

  async createSell (
    createSellInput: CreateSellInput
  ): Promise<CreateSellOutput> {
    try {
      const sell = await this.sells.findOne({
        where: { title: createSellInput.title }
      })

      if (sell) {
        return {
          ok: false,
          error: existErrorMessage(this.message)
        }
      }

      await this.sells.save(await this.sells.create(createSellInput))

      return {
        ok: true
      }
    } catch {
      return {
        ok: false,
        error: createErrorMessage(this.message)
      }
    }
  }

  async allSell (): Promise<AllSellOutput> {
    try {
      const sells = await this.sells.find()

      if (!sells) {
        return {
          ok: false,
          error: notFoundMessage(this.message)
        }
      }

      return {
        ok: true,
        result: sells
      }
    } catch {
      return {
        ok: false,
        error: readErrorMessage(this.message)
      }
    }
  }


}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

NestJS tries to resolve the dependencies it self based on keys, defined in providers. You currently mix JavaScript classes with Nest dependency injection.

To solve your issue, remove the `message` from the constructor like:

```
export class SellService {

private readonly message = 'Зарын'

  constructor (
    @InjectRepository(Sell) private readonly sells: Repository<Sell>) {}
...
}
```

Your message is a constant, so you can simply define it as a private readonly message outside the constructor.